# SQL Server to Oracle to find number of months

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I just did query to find the number of months between two dates (except current month) in SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
    (DATEDIFF(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, '2016-02-20 00:00:00.000') - 
     DAY(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, '2016-02-20 00:00:00.000')), '2016-12-31 00:00:00.000'))
```

The above will return 10 .. how do we achieve this in Oracle?

Comment: What do you mean by "except current month"?

Answer (score 0):

I guess - atleast in 10g and above - the correct function is

```
SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN([date1],[date2]) FROM dual
```

Furthermore it is possible to calculate the difference between two dates

```
SELECT [date2] - [date1] FROM dual
```

This will give you the difference in days.

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways to count a difference in months; 
a good starting point could be [months_between](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions114.htm#SQLRF00669):

```
SQL> with testDates (date1, date2) as
  2  (
  3   select date '2016-12-31', date '2016-02-20' from dual union all
  4   select date '2016-02-01', date '2016-01-31' from dual union all
  5   select date '2016-12-30', date '2016-11-30' from dual union all
  6   select date '2016-12-29', date '2016-11-30' from dual
  7  )
  8  select date1, date2, months_between(date1, date2) diff, floor(months_between(date1, date2)  )  floor_diff
  9  from testDates;

DATE1     DATE2           DIFF FLOOR_DIFF
--------- --------- ---------- ----------
31-DIC-16 20-FEB-16 10,3548387         10
01-FEB-16 31-GEN-16 ,032258065          0
30-DIC-16 30-NOV-16          1          1
29-DIC-16 30-NOV-16 ,967741935          0
```

Answer (score 0):

The Right query to find the sum of months between two dates in Oracle11g..Please try it

SELECT COUNT(0) TOTAL_MONTHS
      FROM (SELECT DATE '2015-01-05' START_DATE,
                   DATE '2015-12-15' END_DATE
              FROM DUAL)
     CONNECT BY LEVEL <= MONTHS_BETWEEN(
                           TRUNC(END_DATE,'MM'),
                           TRUNC(START_DATE,'MM') )
                     + 1